# How to keyframe a shapekey

Tags: animation, keyframes, shape-keys

I am trying to animate a simple scene to test the shape key I added to the object but I tried to keyframe the shape key but I couldn't.

When I keyframe the object after changing the shape key then I go to the next frame and change the shape key to what I want and play the scene the object doesn't change at all

All the tutorials I found were for blender 2.4 which is i guess outdated

How can I keyframe a shapekey?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Just by going by the description of your process for inserting keyframes it sounds like you are only creating 1 keyframe.

The process to animate a property is to:

1. Set the value of the property (in this case the '**Value**' property of the shapekey)
2. Insert a keyframe by pressing <kbd>I</kbd> with the cursor over the **Value** property.
3. Move to a different frame in the timeline.
4. Set the property to a new value.
5. Insert a *second* keyframe on the property.

Keyframes have to be inserted at every point in the timeline where you want the property to change to a specific value.

Comment: I've done this and still nothing happens. I just want my character to open his eyes slowly, so the value is set to 1 ( for eyes closed), i then set the keyframe for frame 1. Then i set the value for 0 (eyes open) to which i set the keyframe to 50. when i hit play from frame 1, nothing happens.

Answer (score 0):

To apply key frames to shape keys hover over the number (or eye) at that shape key, right click that and Insert keyframe. Then move ahead a few frames and change the shape key and repeat.

Answer (score -1):

Hover the mouse over the value of your *Shape Key* and then press the <kbd>I</kbd> key to create the keyframe for the shape key value.

Comment: Hi! How this solution is different to the accepted answer 6 years ago?